# In Ruby how can the last method on a chain access the initial object

Tags: ruby, reference, method-chaining

**- EDIT, SOLVED -**

Ended up creating a method `Object#rec` to accomplish what I needed, this is the result:

```
#$l stores the last object on which Object#rec was called
$l=nil;class Object;def rec;$l=self;end;end

class String
    attr_accessor :ref
    alias_method :old_reverse, :reverse
    def reverse
        self.rec.old_reverse
    end
    def my_method
        $l.ref + ' ' + self
    end
end

a = "Hello"
b = "dlroW" ; b.ref = a

p b.reverse.my_method #=> Hello World
```

If anyone has a better way the question is still open.

**- EDIT, SOLVED -**

---

**The problem:**

I have a situation similar to this:

```
obj.method1.method2
```

where `method1` returns something other than `obj` and I need `method2` to access `obj` again as it holds a reference I need.

---

**For example:**

```
class String
    attr_accessor :ref
    def my_method(b)
        b.ref + ' ' + self
    end
end

a = "Hello"
b = "dlroW" ; b.ref = a

#I want my_method to access 'b.ref' without having to pass 'b'
p b.reverse.my_method(b) #=> Hello World
```

---

**Alternative:**

I know I could avoid having to pass `b` again if I used `obj.my_method` and `my_method` did both reversing(for the example) and accessing the reference, or like commented by `the Tin Man` have `method1` change `obj` but return the original `obj`, but what I want is to know if it's possible or not to accomplish the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with the trivial "obj.method1.method2(obj)"?

Comment: I don't want to bother with the references when using `method2` as `method2` will be an already existing method (MatchData#captures) that should behave normally when the object has no references and only check internally if it does.

Comment: Don't edit your question with the solution. Post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds kind of like you're looking for [`Object.tap`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Object#tap-instance_method):

> Yields x to the block, and then returns x. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

For your example, you might be able to use String's `reverse!` inside the `tap` to manipulate the object. For your application, manipulate the object as you desire inside `tap`, then the object will be passed on to your following method.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of `tap` but it returns the same object and the actual `method1` can't return `self` nor change `obj`, if not I could do what you say and do `obj.method1.method2` where `method1` changes `obj` but returns the original `obj`.